# How to call a function that is using an interface from a button in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, button, interface

I am trying to call a function from a button in WPF.
Here is the function that I'm trying to call:

```
 public RecorderView(IAudioRecorder recorder)
    {
        RecorderViewModel rvm = new RecorderViewModel();
        beginRecordingCommand = new RelayCommand(rvm.BeginRecording, () => recorder.RecordingState == RecordingState.Stopped || recorder.RecordingState == RecordingState.Monitoring);

    }
```

I'm unsure of how to call this function since it is using an interface (IAudioRecorder recorder).
Typically I would just call RecorderView() within the button click event, but how am I supposed to do this since it is using an interface?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a class that implements an interface...

```
class AudioRecorder : IAudioRecorder
{
    //Etc....
```

...and a constructor that expects the interface....

```
public RecorderView(IAudioRecorder recorder)
```

...you can call it with an instance of the class, e.g.

```
var a = new AudioRecorder();
var b = new RecorderView(a);  //a is automatically cast to the interface
```

...or you can instantiate using an IoC container...

```
container.RegisterType<IAudioRecorder, AudioRecorder>();
container.RegisterType<RecorderView, RecorderView();
var b = container.Resolve<RecorderView>();
```

...and the IoC container will populate the constructor argument for you.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've spent the last week trying to figure this one out. I also see that I had the constructor confused for what I was calling the function.